# Job aborted while saving pyspark dataframe to parquet file

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe like this but with billion records and the function below is what I want to achieve.

For this smaller version everything is running fine but when I try to do with whole datframe which has billion records, it's throwing me error.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('a', 'aa', 0.5),
     ('b', 'ab', 0.1),
     ('a', 'ab', 0.2),
     ('a', 'cc', 0.3),
     ('c', 'ab', 0.9),
     ('b', 'bb', 1.0)],
    ['id', 'feature', 'value'])

feature_list = ['aa', 'ab', 'cc', 'bb']

df = df.groupBy('id').agg(F.map_from_entries(F.collect_set(F.struct('feature', 'value'))).alias('map'))
df = df.withColumn('arr', F.array([F.lit(x) for x in feature_list]))
df = df.select('id', F.expr("transform(arr, x -> coalesce(map[x], 0)) feature_vector"))

df.show()
# +---+--------------------+
# | id|      feature_vector|
# +---+--------------------+
# |  c|[0.0, 0.9, 0.0, 0.0]|
# |  b|[0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 1.0]|
# |  a|[0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.0]|
# +---+--------------------+
```

Now when I try to save this to parquet file, I'm getting below error.

```
df.write.paquet('abc.parquet')

out:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o351.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:586)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 73 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 73.5 in stage 1.0 (TID 118512, p13explorpdp01-sw-pdc2.c.wmt-bfdms-p13expprod.internal, executor 77): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 77 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container from a bad node: container_e02_1655172493431_4132_01_000099 on host: p13explorpdp01-sw-pdc2.c.wmt-bfdms-p13expprod.internal. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2022-06-16 21:24:47.656]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2022-06-16 21:24:47.656]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 
[2022-06-16 21:24:47.656]Killed by external signal
.
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1914)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1913)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1913)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:948)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2147)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2096)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2085)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:759)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2076)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:171)
    ... 31 more
```